# Java Scanner object gives a warning to close

Tags: java

How exactly does the Scanner object cause the compiler to give an error if the close method is not run? I want to implement such warnings in some of my classes so is there recommendations of when we should and shouldn't have this?

Comment: You are referring to the [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface I assume

Comment: Are you asking how the compiler warns you?

Comment: Its warning from compiler... what exactly you need?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think it is a bit of both. How the compiler knows to warn you, according to the comment above you it has to do with the Closeable interface. How do I make the compiler warn me for my own classes? If the cause is the Closeable interface how does that Closeable interface make the compiler throw warning if that particular method is not run?

Comment: @SMA I realize that, what I need is what triggers that warning. Obviously Java developers find it makes sense to put it in their classes, so how do I trigger such a warning in my own classes?

Comment: The compiler doesn't emit such warnings. Your IDE, or a plugin of your IDE probaby does. And it probably does because the class implements Closeable. If you showed your code, told us what IDE you're using, and what exact message you get, everything would be much simpler.

Comment: @JBNizet I am using Eclipse, so basically this is an IDE specific warning and it is probably triggered from the interface Closeable? I just thought maybe there was a way to make a warning in code, sort of like an annotation perhaps?

Comment: No there are no annotations as such. Look at this: (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/it.unimi.di/mg4j-big/5.2.1/it/unimi/di/big/mg4j/document/AbstractDocument.java) for how people are implementing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature of Eclipse is NOT something you can easily reuse in your own code. This is how it works: 
[Resource leak analysis](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-avoiding_resource_leaks.htm)

Comment: That is what I meant by saying "not easily". Your only option is limit yourself to certain nterfaces recognized by Eclipse, like Closeable.